# jquery select closest div with ID starting with

Tags: jquery

Using jquery I am trying to find the closest div element
Each line has its div (ui_form_1, ui_form_2 etc)
when user click select this line, the respective div should say "selected"
I am trying to find the closest div with ID starting with ui_form
And modify its text,

This is what I tried so far:

```
selectTypeFormDiv = selectButton.parent().next('div[id^="ui_form_"]');
```

for some reason its not working, code:

```js
function selectTypeClick(selectButton) {
  alert('selectTypeClick');
  selectTypeFormDiv = selectButton.parent().next('div[id^="ui_form_"]');
  selectTypeFormDiv.text("selected!!");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<ol>
  <li>
    <div class="container">
      <input type="hidden" id="typeSave" name="typeSave" value="">
      <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-xs-1"><button class="btn btn-primary">button1</button></div>
        <div class="col-xs-2">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-sm" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-2">
          <button class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#typeModal" onclick="javascript:selectTypeClick($(this))">
     <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
     <span style="width:3em;">
      </span>Select this line
    </button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-1">
          <button class="btn btn-secondary" onclick="alert('this is doing something')">button2</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-1" id="ui_form_1">not selected</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>

  <li>
    <div class="container">
      <input type="hidden" id="typeSave" name="typeSave" value="">
      <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-xs-1"><button class="btn btn-primary">button1</button></div>
        <div class="col-xs-2">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-sm" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-2">
          <button class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#typeModal" onclick="javascript:selectTypeClick($(this))">
     <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
     <span style="width:3em;">
      </span>Select this line
    </button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-1">
          <button class="btn btn-secondary" onclick="alert('this is doing something')">button2</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-1" id="ui_form_2">not selected</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>


  <li>
    <div class="container">
      <input type="hidden" id="typeSave" name="typeSave" value="">
      <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-xs-1"><button class="btn btn-primary">button1</button></div>
        <div class="col-xs-2">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-sm" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-2">
          <button class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#typeModal" onclick="javascript:selectTypeClick($(this))">
     <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
     <span style="width:3em;">
      </span>Select this line
    </button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-1">
          <button class="btn btn-secondary" onclick="alert('this is doing something')">button2</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-1" id="ui_form_3">not selected</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>

  <li>
    <div class="container">
      <input type="hidden" id="typeSave" name="typeSave" value="">
      <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-xs-1"><button class="btn btn-primary">button1</button></div>
        <div class="col-xs-2">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-sm" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-2">
          <button class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#typeModal" onclick="javascript:selectTypeClick($(this))">
     <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
     <span style="width:3em;">
      </span>Select this line
    </button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-1">
          <button class="btn btn-secondary" onclick="alert('this is doing something')">button2</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-1" id="ui_form_4">not selected</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>

</ol>
```

Comment: The element you want is not the immediate sibling.  It is the next over sibling.  `next()` will only go one over.  The selector you give it is a filter to tell it if it should return an element at all.  It will not skip over elements until it finds one that matches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should search in the [`.siblings()`](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/) of the `.parent()` and not the [`.next()`](https://api.jquery.com/next/) div of the parent.

```
selectButton.parent().siblings('div[id^="ui_form_"]');
```

Check the documentation of both for more info. Here's the working snippet -

```js
function selectTypeClick(selectButton) {
  selectTypeFormDiv = selectButton.parent().siblings('div[id^="ui_form_"]');
  selectTypeFormDiv.text("selected!!");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<ol>
  <li>
    <div class="container">
      <input type="hidden" id="typeSave" name="typeSave" value="">
      <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-xs-1"><button class="btn btn-primary">button1</button></div>
        <div class="col-xs-2">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-sm" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-2">
          <button class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#typeModal" onclick="javascript:selectTypeClick($(this))">
     <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
     <span style="width:3em;">
      </span>Select this line
    </button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-1">
          <button class="btn btn-secondary" onclick="alert('this is doing something')">button2</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-1" id="ui_form_1">not selected</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>

  <li>
    <div class="container">
      <input type="hidden" id="typeSave" name="typeSave" value="">
      <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-xs-1"><button class="btn btn-primary">button1</button></div>
        <div class="col-xs-2">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-sm" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-2">
          <button class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#typeModal" onclick="javascript:selectTypeClick($(this))">
     <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
     <span style="width:3em;">
      </span>Select this line
    </button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-1">
          <button class="btn btn-secondary" onclick="alert('this is doing something')">button2</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-1" id="ui_form_2">not selected</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>


  <li>
    <div class="container">
      <input type="hidden" id="typeSave" name="typeSave" value="">
      <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-xs-1"><button class="btn btn-primary">button1</button></div>
        <div class="col-xs-2">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-sm" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-2">
          <button class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#typeModal" onclick="javascript:selectTypeClick($(this))">
     <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
     <span style="width:3em;">
      </span>Select this line
    </button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-1">
          <button class="btn btn-secondary" onclick="alert('this is doing something')">button2</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-1" id="ui_form_3">not selected</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>

  <li>
    <div class="container">
      <input type="hidden" id="typeSave" name="typeSave" value="">
      <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-xs-1"><button class="btn btn-primary">button1</button></div>
        <div class="col-xs-2">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-sm" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-2">
          <button class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#typeModal" onclick="javascript:selectTypeClick($(this))">
     <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
     <span style="width:3em;">
      </span>Select this line
    </button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-1">
          <button class="btn btn-secondary" onclick="alert('this is doing something')">button2</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-1" id="ui_form_4">not selected</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>

</ol>
```

Comment: Thank you its working great do you think there is a shorter/better way to find that div? because that expression is kinda bulky